# Give Azure AD login permissions to SQL Azure

Tags: sql, azure, permissions, active-directory, office365

Hi I'm following the instructions below here to create a bcs external list from an Azure SQL DB. I have an Office 365 developer subscription which is where my Sharepoint site is and my Azure AD.

I have another subscription with which I created a database. I'm following the instructions but it says **"The account used in this example already has access to the Azure SQL database which is a requirement for the connectivity to work."**

I can't figure out how to assign my azure login permissions to SQL Server. How do I do this. Thanks.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28286.office-365-sharepoint-online-bcs-with-azure-sql-server-database.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the step 'Create a Secure Store Service ID' in that Technet article shows you how to setup a secure credential store in SharePoint so that you can pass the credentials when you use BCS to log into Azure SQL Database.

The credentials you use are the SQL Login you setup for this purpose (recommending that you don't default to using the admin account you configured when you setup the Azure SQL DB instance).

Comment: It's just that the user is in the form of an email address which I assumed is an azure account. I'll give it a try tomorrow.